# how to read terraform list from vars file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a list of subnets as list in the vars file, which I want to read a list inside the AWS resource.

```
variables.tf
variable "alb_subnets" {
 type = list(string)
}

terraform.tfvars
subnets = ["subnet-a","subnet-b"]

main.tf
resource "<resource_name>" "test" {
  name               = var.Name
  security_groups    = ["${join(",",var.subnets)}"]
}

Error: ValidationError: subnet 'subnet-a,subnet-b' is not valid
        status code: 400, request id: dc4be07e-e353-4821-8bde-3d9849584bef
```

what is the right way to read the list as list inside the AWS resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would just do:

```
security_groups = var.subnets
```

However, it seems to me that you are trying to assign **subnets as security groups**. Even if you fix the syntax, this will not work. For `security_groups` you need security groups, not subnets.

Comment: yeah, I looking for subnets and reading multiple subnets available in a variable subnets as list inside the AWS resource section. Will check like you mentioned @Marcin